# python threads gui

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a small issue when working with PyQt4 and threading package:

My code looks like this:

```
def goForwardToSamples(self):
    self.main.dataSet = DataSetProvider(self.main.sourceFile)
    self.ui = Ui_NeuralPredictor2()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    ParalelGui(self.ui).start()
    self.connectSignalsWindow2()
def connectSignalsWindw2(self):
   # DOING SOME REAL SERIOUS COMPUTATION ...
```

=> now def run(self): in ParalelGui class looks like this:

```
def run(self):
    self.gui.show()
```

=> I just want to test if my GUI will run paralel with the computation.

I feel I know what the problem is. I have a QtableView that is being filled with data where I wrote (*DOING SOME REAL SERIOUS COMPUTATION..*). That QtableView is of course part of ui that I am sending to ParalelGui thread to be shown. I am not really sure how to make it work... Basically I would like to have a part of GUI threaded and already shown while the other part is being filled up dynamically in different thread.

What happens now is the typical 'you didnt thread your gui freeze' ... help much appreciated

Comment: What is `ParalelGui`? Are you trying to show your gui in a different thread than it was created? Also are you using the `QThread` class? We need a little more context here of your code structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your example is highly limited, I am going to take a stab at what I think you are doing here...

To me, it seems like you are doing things backwards and trying to show your gui in a thread while doing heavy computation in your main thread?

What you really should be doing is creating and showing your gui in the main thread, and running heavy computation in a separate worker thread. This worker thread can then emit a signal when data is ready, which your main thread can connect to and quickly update your table. This way you don't block your main thread. The rule of thumb is never do anything heavy in the main thread. Its meant for the GUI and its events.

Also, make sure you are using the QThread class and not the python threading module.

Comment: thank you very MUCH! Thats exactly what I needed to know... I realized it yesterday (that main thread is aimed to gui) and fixed it the other way around (doing the computation in another thread, keeping the main gui-only). Now I used Thread from threading... I will try out QThread later today

Comment: The benefit of using QThread is that it comes with signals since its a QObject. Its trivial to add and emit more signals at any point in the run() routine. QThread also supports event loops in case you want to create gui objects there and have them be able to receive events and connect to other signals.

Comment: Correction. What I meant is that a QThread supports event loops so that you can move any QObject to them and have their events and signal/slots run there. Not QWidgets.